# which version of mvc is using in asp.net core 2.0? is is MVC 6 or use different name?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc

which version of mvc is using in asp.net core 2.0? is is MVC 6 or use different name ? 
What is .net 5? 
what is .net standard ?

these questions are from an interview.plz help

Comment: why it is down voted?.

Comment: I was wondering the same. The command `dotnet --version` returned `3.1.112`. A search for mvc inside `myProjectFolder\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\myProjectFolder.deps.json` returned a bunch of hits with `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.*` all referencing version 3.1

Answer (score 0):

The .NET Standard is a formal specification of .NET APIs that are intended to be available on all .NET implementations.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard .ASP.NET5.0 Is Called ASP.NET Core 1.0 and In the ASP.NET Core 1.0 release, Web API is merged with ASP.NET MVC, termed as MVC 6

Comment: thanks for relay , can u give me link for asp.net core 1.0=mvc 6 , i am actually asking about asp.net core 2.0

Comment: please have a look a the following link: https://forums.asp.net/t/2102228.aspx?What+is+the+difference+between+ASP+Net+MVC+6+0+and+ASP+Net+MVC+Core+  and  http://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet/1402/aspnet-core-2-new-features

Answer (score 0):

They're totally unrelated. "MVC 6" was sort of like a codename for Core when it was still in early stages. ASP.NET MVC and ASP.NET Web Api are totally separate from ASP.NET Core. Now, it's just "Core". There is no "MVC" or "Web Api", because Core controllers do both functions. ASP.NET MVC and ASP.NET Web Api live on and although they will probably eventually be deprecated, they could presumably (though not likely at all) get new releases. At the very least, they'll be patched for the foreseeable future.

ASP.NET Core is a complete rewrite from the ground up. It was originally created simply to be a cross-platform alternative to ASP.NET, and I think the original plan was to keep both ASP.NET and ASP.NET Core as potential development options. However, as ASP.NET Core became more competent, it has pretty fully eclipsed ASP.NET; we now have a cross-platform framework that can run on Windows, Mac and Linux and can do virtually anything the Windows-only framework can. Therefore, why keep the Windows-only framework?

Comment: it is still confusing ,different guys have different answers. do you have any Microsoft sites link saying MVC6=asp.net core.so there will be no mvc7 since mvc 6 is code name in early stages ?

Comment: There wasn't like some sort of announcement where Microsoft formally said "From this point hence, MVC 6 shall be known only as Core." It was just sort of a thought evolution. The original idea was to create a version of ASP.NET, based on MVC, that could be deployed outside of Wndows. Since MVC 5 was current, it was referred to as MVC 6. However, during development it diverged more and more to the point where they were completely different platforms and not a simple next major release.

Comment: MVC 6 essentially became Core 1.0 and of course now we have Core 2.0. MVC 5, should it ever get a new version would become MVC 6, but given the track of Core, MVC will almost assuredly be deprecated in favor of Core. Currently, Microsoft has committed to continue to support the MVC track, but of course all new development and initiatives are focused on Core.

Answer (score 0):

Asp.net Core 2.0 is MVC 6 and The framework is 4.6.1
To start with development you need to have VS-2017 and for 1.X you can start with VS-2015.
Please refer the below link for clear presentation of .NetCore 2.0 so that you can get good knowledge to kick start your development.

[Official Asp.Net Core Documentation Url](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/)